# Renderizar un componente de React despues de fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo este codigo, que es el del componente *Grid*, que genera la lista de riders disponible a partir del la información grabada en el LocalStorage, el problema está en que renderiza antes de que llegue la información, y aun que después se carga bien no lo vuelve a renderizar. **¿Creéis que podría solucionarlo con el useContext? o ¿cuál seria la mejor solución?
Gracias.**

Este es el componente:

```
import { useEffect, useReducer, useState } from "react"
import { ridersReducer } from "../hooks/ridersReducer";
import { GridRow } from "./GridRow";

// En este componente generamos el grid de la app

export const Grid = ({ pressed, setPressed }) => {


 //eslint-disable-next-line
    const [ state, dispatch ] = useReducer(ridersReducer, []);
    const [ riders, setRiders ] = useState([]);

    useEffect( () => {
        dispatch({
            type: 'read'
        });
        // Con el dispatch en update actualizamos los riders
        // Recuperamos el estado de los riders del localStorage
        setRiders(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('riders')));
    }, [pressed]);
    
    // Retornamos nuestro componente
    return (
        <table className="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Horas</th>
                <th scope="col">Free Riders</th>
                <th scope="col">Estado</th>
                <th scope="col">Reservar</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {
                // Comprobamos que los riders no sean null y llamamos a 
                // GridRow para generar cada fila de la tabla
                riders !== null &&(
                    Object.keys(riders).map( rider => (
                        <GridRow 
                            id={ riders[rider].id }
                            key={ riders[rider].id }
                            hora={ riders[rider].Hora }
                            riders={ riders[rider].Riders }
                            pressed={ pressed }
                            setPressed={ setPressed }
                            dispatch={ dispatch }
                        />
                        ))
                )
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    )
    }
```

Y esta la llamada:

```
import { getRiders } from "../helpers/getRiders";
import { updateRiders } from "../helpers/updateRiders";

export const ridersReducer = ( state, action ) => {

// Definimos las diferentes acciones que hará nuestro reducer
switch (action.type){

    case 'read':
        localStorage.clear();
        getRiders()
        .then( data => {
            // Guardamos los riders en el estado
            if( JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('riders') === null )){
                state = data.record;
            } else {
                state = [...JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('riders')), data.record];
                }
            })
            .then( () => {
                // Guardamos el estado de los riders en el localStorage para poder
                // recuperarlos desde el componente Grid y poder mostrarlo
                localStorage.setItem('riders', JSON.stringify(state));
            });
        return state;

    case 'update':
        updateRiders()
        break;
    
    default:
        return state;
};

};
```

**Aprovecho también para preguntar, porque cuando llamo a state que lo recupero desde ridersReducer desestructurándolo siempre me devuelve valor null, cuando ya devuelvo el nuevo estado en el componente.
Disculpad si pregunto cosas muy obvias, estoy empezando en el mundillo y sólo quiero aprender y mejorar.
Gracias de nuevo!**

Comment: Saludos, este codigo es tuyo o copiado de algun tutorial? Lo digo más que nada porque si estás empezando con react, quizá es mejor empezar con ejercicios más sencillos, solo usando useState y useEffect para luego entrar en contextAPI, sino no terminarás de entender bien lo que hace cada uno de estos Hooks.

Comment: Tu puedes hacer un fetch dentro de useEffect y luego pasar por props el resultado que te de a un LocalStorage o directamente al componente que lo necesite. Si el sentido es de padre a hijo. No creo que sea buena idea complicarse con UseContext o cosas así, para empezar. Un Saludo